# How to get android device name in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-3.0

I try to get android **Device name**.

Now I am using package [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) v4.1.2, but it can't get this info.

[image]

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
```

*Output*

```
print('Running on Product ${androidInfo.product}'); --show sdk_gphone_x86_arm
print('Running on Board ${androidInfo.board}'); --show oldfish_x86
print('Running on Device ${androidInfo.device}'); --show generic_x86_arm
print('Running on Model ${androidInfo.model}'); --show AOSP on IA Emulator
```

Could you guys recommend the other one that can get that info?

Comment: I also try to use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) cannot get the device name too.

Comment: I also try to use [device_information](https://pub.dev/packages/device_information/install) v0.0.4 cannot get the device name too.

Answer (score -1):

In device_info_plus package after getting the android info, read the values `board` and `product`.

Like this:

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Running on ${androidInfo.product}');
print('Running on ${androidInfo.board}');
```

Comment: I've update this package to v4.1.2, From you code it show "Running on sdk_gphone_x86_arm", "Running on goldfish_x86"

Comment: Could you try this on a physical device?

Comment: I am running the app on a Samsung note 10 lite.
`- androidInfo.product show r7nsxx,
- androidInfo.board show exynos9810,
- androidInfo.device show r7`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think any third party libraries currently provide it. So, to get that you have to write native code. Please clarify if that's what you want? I shall post the native code if required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my app was finished. I don't want to develop the new one with native code. I will be waiting for some package that can get the device name info (I wish ^^).